# SharePoint workflows gather approvers from list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, workflow

Is it possible to create a workflow that pulls all approvers from a list? Example I have a list that contains the approvers name, company. I would like the workflow to look at the list and grab all the approvers listed for that company, and then assign a task for them.

I was able to get it working using a Lookup, only it just grabs the top item in the list.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using 2013?

Comment: I am using o365, and 2013 workflows.

Comment: Research using a loop in the workflow to iterate through the lookup list.

Answer (score 0):

With Visial Studio workflow, you can easily code this.

With SP Designer, the only way I can see this happening is if you creat one item in your list with a multiple person field that has all of your approvers. You can then look up that one item and use the person field as the target of an approval process.